# How to fix java heap space out of memory when using many successive images

Tags: java, image, javafx, jasper-reports, heap-memory

Trying to perform some printings using JasperReport.

JasperReport provides a function to print a document to a BufferedImage, which i convert to a WritableImage to display it on an ImageView object (as shown in the code below).

By time i get a Java Heap space out of memory exception in the getImage(int pageNumber) function. My guess is that the old references to the images are not freed.

Is it possible to fix that ?

```
private void viewPage(int pageNumber) throws JRException {
    this.resultViewer.setFitHeight(this.imageHeight * this.zoomFactor);
    this.resultViewer.setFitWidth(this.imageWidth * this.zoomFactor);
    this.resultViewer.setImage(this.getImage(pageNumber));
}

@FXML
private ImageView resultViewer;

private WritableImage getImage(int pageNumber) throws JRException {
    return SwingFXUtils
            .toFXImage((BufferedImage) JasperPrintManager.printPageToImage(this.jasperPrint, pageNumber, 2), null);
}
```

Comment: Why i've got a -2 :O ? duplicate post ? worthless post ? what's wrong with that ? o.O

Comment: Please create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). To sum it up it is a Minimal(small amount of code) Complete(Fully runnable but don't post your whole project i've seen people do it) Verifiable(I can put into my IDE and run without expected errors) Example(Recreate your problem).

Comment: I fixed the problem by caling flush() function on the last displayed BufferedImage before displaying a next one.

Comment: You should post it as an answer so if others find the question they know how to solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem by caling flush() function on the last displayed BufferedImage before displaying a next one